# Decompose complex shear wave field into propagation directions

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

Using phase contrast MRI, I recorded images of harmonic propagating shear waves in in vivo brain tissue in a 2D axial slice (126x126 pixel at 1.6mm x 1.6mm resolution). I recorded 8 images over one vibration cycle, from which I extracted the harmonic motion (complex valued wave field) using the temporal Fourier transform.

[image: Antomic image of 2D axial slice] [image: Real part of complex wave field]

Here you see the animated wave in a different slice for illustration:

[image: Animated wave field]

Next, I would like to decompose this wave field into different propagation directions or plane waves (**locally plane**) in order to calculate the **local** phase gradient on those plane waves. This does not work for superimposed waves. Therefore I calculated the spatial Fourier transform of the wave field and multiplied with directional filters (gaussian filter) and performed the inverse Fourier transform to end up with decomposed waves in for example 8 directions. However I am afraid that the filter in Fourier space, as it is shown in the image, introduces artifacts to the filtered wave fields. As a final step, I use the decomposed wave fields to reconstruct a 2D map of local wave numbers and wave speed based on the gradient of the phase of the complex waves. The result is illustrated here:

[image]

How would you decompose a complex valued shear wave field into it's main propagation direction such that the plane wave assumption fo the phase gradient calculation is fullfilled?

[image: Directional Filter]
The Matlab code to decompose the wavefield into 8 propagation direction is given below. Moreover example data for Matlab (waveField_single.mat) and a plot script can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g3_so9WTx5N4YjeSGl94kvCrqQD3QS76?usp=sharing

```
% Filter waveField into 8 propagation directions
clearvars
load('waveField_single.mat')

n = 126;
reso = 1.6;
nTheta = 8;% number of directions

fourierWF = fftshift( fft2(waveField) );    % in-plane fourier transformation
k1 = -( (0:n-1)-fix(n/2) ) / (n*reso) * 2 * pi;%[rad/m] wavenumber in 1st direction
k2 =  ( (0:n-1)-fix(n/2) ) / (n*reso) * 2 * pi;%[rad/m] wavenumber in 2nd direction
[theta, rho] = cart2pol( repmat(k2,[n,1]), repmat(k1',[1, n]) );% transform to polar coordinates

% calculate the angles of directions
sigmaTheta = 2 * pi / nTheta;
thetaValue= 2 * pi * linspace( 0, 1-1/nTheta, nTheta);%[rad]
filter = zeros( n ,n , nTheta );

for iTheta = 1 : nTheta % loop over directions
    currentThetaValue = thetaValue( iTheta );%[rad] selected theta value
    currentTheta = angle( exp( 1i * (theta-currentThetaValue) ) ); %[rad]  rotated theta
    filter(:,:,iTheta) = 0.4 * exp( -1/2 * ( currentTheta/sigmaTheta ).^2 );% gaussian function with selected theta (0.4=theta function(1/sqrt(e))
    filterdFourierWF = fourierWF .* filter(:,:,iTheta);
    waveField_filt(:, :, 1, iTheta) = ifft2(ifftshift(filterdFourierWF));% inverse fft
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with your field decomposition? You seem to have picked a rather high temporal frequency component (compared to the frequency content of your original signal) for the images shown, but they look nice!

Comment: For clarification, do you mean that in the bottom pictures, the wavelength of the decomposed images (right side) appears shorter than the wavelength of the input image on the left?

Comment: Yes! The frequency content seems much higher in the decomposed field than in the original complexed value field. Were all the images computed with the same selected temporal frequency ( of 30 Hz, as you mention)?

Comment: Yes, it's all the same frequency of 30 Hz. That's why I wonder if the Fourier decomposition using these radial cones alters the wavelength and therefore introduces an error.

Comment: I would assume somethnig's wrong with your algorithm, then...

Comment: I don't think the code is wrong, but I could imagine, that the convolution with a Gaussian shaped cone as it is illustrated in the middle of the last image introduces wave length alterations. The filter is smooth along its circumference, however has sharp boundaries along its radius, meaning at the boundary between positive and negative frequencies and at the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: As far as I know the discrete Fourier transform leads to frequency leakage into other bins and even into the negative side of the spectrum. If you cut the leaked bins by nulling the negative frequencies and perform the inverse transform, this would change your image and possibly the apparent wavelength.

Comment: Your signal should have 0 energy close to the origin so you could in principle design  "annular" portions of smoothing functions in Fourier space if you think the sharp discontinuity in the corner is a problem. I might be wrong but I hardly believe this is the case, the artefacts generated would be at  much higher frequencies. You could post your complete Matlab code if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I attached the Matlab code to the post and would appreciate if you take a look at it. Kind regards.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine as far as I can see, I have attached the output image I obtain in my answer below. It is consistent with what I would expect as the output. Are you sure something's not wrong with your colormap or the scaling of the pixel values in your final display?

Comment: Yes you were right, I extracted the image from an older presentation and only updated the input wave field. My apologies. I replaced the image now.

Answer (score 0):

The spatial Fourier transform precisely does a decomposition of your field into plane waves. A local peak in the Fourier decomposition with $k_{x}$, $k_y$ coordinates indicate that the field has a plane wave component propagating at angle $\theta=atan\frac{k_{y}}{k_{x}}$ and wavenumber $k^{2}=k_{x}^2+k_{y}^{2}$. The gradient of the phase of a plane wave points along the propagation direction (given by the wavenumber vector) and with norm, the wavenumber. So I suggest you work directly in the Fourier domain to obtain the wavenumbers associated with the relevant peaks.

EDIT : this is the output of your code on my computer, the colormap is the standard "jet" from matlab

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed that would give me the dominant frequencies and wave numbers present in my image. However I would like to obtain a 2D map of local wavenumbers, from which I can compute the local wave speed. Therefore I need to go back to image space if I am right. I added a final map of shear wave speed to my original post as illustration.

Comment: This is avery interesting problem, I know this is what they do in MRE to obtain maps of the shear moduli in elastic tissues. I never quite understood how the algorithm used for this application works to be honest, and I'm a bit dubious about the obtention of such a high resolution mapping in $V_{s}$!

Comment: Suggestion: could you not detect isophase contours directly from your complex-valued harmonic field and take the gradient along  the local normal to these contours?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will give it a try. Indeed I am working in the field of MRE.